# How to avoiding skipped months in Python pivot table when all entires in table are 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which I sort index by year then month from a pandas dataframe column with timestamp objects. This works great for what I need except for one detail. If there are no entries for a particular month/year that particular row in the pivot table is not populated.

I need it to show as 0 for all entries and not skip over the months. How can I accomplish this?

Some example data can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/temp

Curent code I have to generate the pivot table is below. Unfortunately I do not know an effective way to share the resulting data, however it's the months in 2016 that are not showing for the index and column

```
data2['MonthDateBuild']=data2.DateBuild.dt.month
data2['YearDateBuild']=data2.DateBuild.dt.year
data2['MonthDateOpen']=data2.DateOpen.dt.month
data2['YearDateOpen']=data2.DateOpen.dt.year
pd.pivot_table(data2,index=['YearDateBuild','MonthDateBuild'],values=['Quantity'],columns=['YearDateOpen','MonthDateOpen'])
```

Comment: please show us the code you are using to produce this table and the source data.

Comment: You can use pandas `date_range` to generate a complete range of dates; and then `reindex` your dataframe with the option `fill_value=0`. There's some work to do about the multiindexes, but to help you with that it'd be a lot better if you provided your source data as @ShawnMehan said

Comment: The link to data @ShawnMehan is added to the post for reference as well as the code I'm using to generate the pivot table in question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this meet your expectation? Use `.fillna` if you want padding.

```
pv = pd.pivot_table(data2,index=pd.Grouper(key='DateBuild', freq='M'),
                    values='Quantity',
                    columns=pd.Grouper(key='DateOpen', freq='M'))
pv.reindex(index=pd.date_range(pv.index.min(), pv.index.max(), freq='M'),
       columns=pd.date_range(pv.columns.min(), pv.columns.max(), freq='M'))
#             2013-05-31  2013-06-30  2013-07-31  2013-08-31     ...      \
# 2012-06-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2012-07-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2012-08-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2012-09-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# ...                ...         ...         ...         ...     ...
# 2016-02-29         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2016-03-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2016-04-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 2016-05-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     ...
# 
#             2016-05-31  2016-06-30  2016-07-31  2016-08-31
# 2012-06-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2012-07-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2012-08-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2012-09-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# ...                ...         ...         ...         ...
# 2016-02-29         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2016-03-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2016-04-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
# 2016-05-31         NaN         NaN         NaN           1
# 
# [48 rows x 40 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you this works as desired. If possible, could you explain a bit of what the pd.Grouper function is doing?

Comment: Pls see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#grouping-with-a-grouper-specification). It's specialized way to allow more flexible grouping, such as grouping by month.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link

Comment: Is there a way to pad the dates? For example if my 'DateBuild' series has a date range of 12-01-2013 to 12-01-2015 but I want to include a range of say 12-01-2012 to 12-01-2016, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: You can change the ``reindex`` arguments like ``pv.reindex(index=pd.date_range('2012-12-01', '2016-12-01', freq='M'), ...)``